# Whether $f(x_1,\cdots,x_N)=\log\sum_{n=1}^Na_nx_n$ has a bound or an approximation expression.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Consider a function $f(x_1,\cdots,x_N)=\log\sum_{n=1}^Na_nx_n$, where $a_n\in[0,1]$, $x_n\in[0,1]$, $n=1,2,\cdots,N$.

Whether $f(x_1,\cdots,x_N)$ has a bound or an approximation expression?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It has a tight upper bound equal to $\log \sum_{n=1}^N a_n x_n$. Seriously, you have to put more effort into the question or we can't say anything useful.

Comment: It's trivial that $-\infty < f(x_1, \dots, x_N) \leq \log N$.